# authenticating my users in mobile api with passport

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I want to do this:

- Mobile app, make a request to the server with username/email and password or just a 5 digit code that takes from his website dashboard
- Server will validate those credentials or code and if they are correct, create an access token and send back in response
- For all other subsequent requests, client will send that token in the request so that server can authenticate and process the request

What I have done:

Installed passport, added passport routes in kernel, added HasTokenApi to user model, Ran artisan commands for install passport.

I have a client type password with client id 2 and a code.

A user email:t@t.t pass: 123456

this is how I get the access token:

```
            $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
            $url = "http://likebot.dev/";
            $urlApi = "http://likebot.dev/api/";
            $response = $client->post($url . 'oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'client_id' => 2,
                    // The secret generated when you ran: php artisan passport:install
                    'client_secret' => 'oG0mEGRiVsH6xzOjCIu5C63w1bIJfHUXQyoUF2Ni',
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'username' => 't@t.t',
                    'password' => '123456',
                    'scope' => '*',
                ],
            ]);

            // You'd typically save this payload in the session
            $auth = json_decode((string) $response->getBody());
            echo ($auth->access_token);
```

This is my route in api.php route:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

And this is how I use access token:

```
            $accessToken = 'access-token-here';
            $response = $client->get($urlApi . 'user', [
                'headers' => [
                    // 'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
                ],
            ]);
            // ee($response);
            $user = json_decode((string) $response->getBody());

            ee($user);
```

The problem is than response is empty even if I return a string or anything else, And when I uncomment `// 'Accept' => 'application/json',` from headers when I use access token this will response a 401 status code with `{'message': 'unauthorized'}` message!

Comment: May I recommend you look at JWT (Json Web Token) instead of Passport's OAuth2? OAuth2 may be overkill for app-to-Laravel communication. I've found myself in a similar situation and JWT is easier to setup and manage (it's also stateless, which means that no information needs to be stored in your database).

Comment: @Jeffrey Actually I was thinking about that you are right! but the problem is that I can't pass this issue until it get fixed :)) anyway if this got fixed either  I will use JWT ;) Thanks.

Comment: @HassanShojaei Small note. Unless you want to use Auth0 SDK, I would rather stick with Passport, cause it gives you much more flexibility and your need for addtional functionality will probably grow over time...

Answer (score 1):

For those who has this issue!

After @jeffrey suggested, I started to use JWT when I was reading the documents it said Apache has some problem with Authorization header and I should add some codes to Apache config! so I added this to .htaccess and the problem got fixed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```